# Jump to Main Screen of Game in Cocos2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have started development in cocos2d iphone before few months back. Now I am about to finish my game,  and I stuck at one position. And i know this is coding issue.

First I want to explain main screen. When may game starts, there are some animations which takes around 7 seconds and then my Play Button appear. Then i click on that and game starts.

Now i want to implement one button , when i click on that button , scene will be transit and then directly i can see my main menu without animation.

So basically i don't want user to wait for animation to be finished first. I want them to play game directly.

Any guideline or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented on demo code in which i put three different button. Every button will go to same class's scene but every time it will display different scenerio as par button clicked.

This is a **HelloWorldLayer.h**

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{
}

// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene:(int)level;
+(id)nodeWithGameLevel:(int)level;
-(id) initWithGameLevel:(int)level;
@end
```

**HelloWorldLayer.m** class

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
+(CCScene *) scene:(int)whichLevel
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer nodeWithGameLevel:whichLevel];
    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
-(id) initWithGameLevel:(int)level
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        printf("level:%d",level);
        if (level == 1) {
            //Code for scene with full animation.
        }else if(level == 2){
            //code for scene without animation.
        }else if(level == 3){
            // any other scene which you want.
        }
        CCMenuItemImage *item1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Icon-72.png" selectedImage:@"Icon-72.png" target:self selector:@selector(goToMainMenu)];
        CCMenuItemImage *item2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Icon-72.png" selectedImage:@"Icon-72.png" target:self selector:@selector(goToRestartMenu)];
        CCMenuItemImage *item3 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Icon-72.png" selectedImage:@"Icon-72.png" target:self selector:@selector(goToMainPage)];
        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1,item2,item3, nil];
        [self addChild:menu];
        [menu alignItemsVertically];
    }
    return self;
}

+(id)nodeWithGameLevel:(int)level{
    return  [[[self alloc] initWithGameLevel:level] autorelease];
}
-(void)goToMainMenu{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene:1] withColor:ccWHITE]];
}
-(void)goToRestartMenu{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene:2] withColor:ccWHITE]];
}
-(void)goToMainPage{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene:3] withColor:ccWHITE]];
}
```